# Async/Await Promise implementation is executing a single S3 PutObject call Twice - Why?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, async-await, promise

I'm using the node.js SDK to put objects into an S3 bucket. Everything is working fine, however in the logs I notice that on each invoke of my Lambda, it performs the putObject operation twice, even though it's only in the code once. I believe it has to do with how I'm using the promise via the async/await way (verses dealing with promise.then.hell

Any help would be appreciated. Code below.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
if (process.env.AWS_CONSOLE_LOGGER_ENABLED === "true") {
  AWS.config.logger = console;
}
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let returnObject = { status: true };

  try {
    /**
     *
     * Snip out code above - not relevant
     *
     */

    let s3ObjectBody = {
      numParticipants: numParticipants,
      ballDropOrder: currentBallDropOrder,
      ballDropSeconds: 0,
      allPrizesWon: allPrizesWon,
      roundHasEnded: false,
      winners: winners,
    };
    let s3Params = {
      Body: JSON.stringify(s3ObjectBody),
      Bucket: `my-bucket-${process.env.DEPLOYMENT_STAGE}`,
      Key: `public/${gameIdAndVersion}.json`,
      ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    };
    await S3.putObject(s3Params, async function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        const message = "S3.putObject failed for s3Params: " + s3Params + ",  exiting. error: " + error;
        errorCode = "S3_TEST_PUT_OBJECT_UPDATE_EXCEPTION";
        await notify(true, true, true, "CRIT", context.functionName, errorCode + " - " + message, { logGroupName: CWLGN, logStreamName: CWLSN, awsRequestId: ARID });
        returnObject = { status: false, errorCode: errorCode };
        return returnObject;
      } else {
        console.log("S3 putObject response data: ", data);
      }
    }).promise();

    /**
         *  First putObject executes successfully (returns 200), and I have an S3 Object version (ending w/ VnPuck)
         * 
         *  2021-02-11T15:00:41.973Z    744c8952-134b-4ded-9d1c-e2ef45ed083f    INFO    [AWS s3 200 0.088s 0 retries] putObject({ Body:
            '{"numParticipants":12,"ballDropOrder":[47],"ballDropSeconds":0,"allPrizesWon":false,"roundHasEnded":false,"winners":[]}',
            Bucket: 'my-bucket-dev',
            Key:
            'public/5c8d8e30-f0f8-4eae-a252-50afb3086f1c-2894.json',
            ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' })
        
            2021-02-11T15:00:41.973Z    744c8952-134b-4ded-9d1c-e2ef45ed083f    INFO    S3 putObject response data:  { ETag: '"6a447cd0092d51706756cd18c1c8cf6f"',
            VersionId: 'VipS0SJ_dzvqbE6BRjcxwdD4lvVnPuck' }
        
            But now it does another putObject, and returns a different version (ending w/ yFlrDkO_), so why the second put???? 

            2021-02-11T15:00:41.986Z    744c8952-134b-4ded-9d1c-e2ef45ed083f    INFO    [AWS s3 200 0.101s 0 retries] putObject({ Body:
            '{"numParticipants":12,"ballDropOrder":[47],"ballDropSeconds":0,"allPrizesWon":false,"roundHasEnded":false,"winners":[]}',
            Bucket: 'my-bucket-dev',
            Key:
            'public/5c8d8e30-f0f8-4eae-a252-50afb3086f1c-2894.json',
            ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' })
        
            2021-02-11T15:00:41.986Z    744c8952-134b-4ded-9d1c-e2ef45ed083f    INFO    S3 putObject response data:  { ETag: '"6a447cd0092d51706756cd18c1c8cf6f"',
            VersionId: 'dhfyxk2RXM8T0BycL4RYRhTeyFlrDkO_' }
        */

    /**
     *
     * Snip out code below - not relevant
     *
     */

    return returnObject;
  } catch (e) {
    /**
     *
     * Snip out code - not relevant
     *
     */
  }
};
```

Comment: Please check your client side whether the request is firing twice or any mechanism written to retry the previous requests on failure.

Comment: Nope, not firing twice, that would be two separate lambda invokes, and hence the awsRequestId would be different across the two putObject executions.

Comment: Did you try removing `.promise()` and then checked?

Answer (score 0):

How have you mapped your API Gateway methods to the Lambda function? I've noticed when using the ANY method --> Lambda integration the function will run twice, once for the OPTIONS request and again for the actual GET / POST / whatever (if the request is not simple, generated by XMLHttpRequest for example).

This wil run it once: [image: will run once]

But if you have this it will run twice:

[image]

Comment: That is good to know however this Lambda is invoked from another Lambda via the SDK, Lambda.Invoke(), API Gateway is not in the picture. You can see by the logs that this single invoke of the lambda shows the two S3.putObject entries in the logs, with the same awsRequestId (744c8952-134b-4ded-9d1c-e2ef45ed083f ), which proves its the same execution/single invoke of the Lambda.